# waitpid wrong usage?

Tags: c, unix, exit-code, waitpid

I am trying to access the EXIT STATUS of the forked child process from the parent, but I am getting weird answers. Sometimes, I get 256 or sometimes I get a negative number depending upon whether I specify &status or just status. I know I am really close. Can someone provide me with a little help how I will get the EXIT_STATUS

Here is my code

```
pid_t  pid;
int *status;
if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    fprintf(stdout, "Error forking child process\n");

else if (pid == 0)
{
    execvp(input[0], input);
    fprintf(stdout, "Invalid process!!\n");
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
else
{
    while (waitpid(-1, status, 0) != pid);
    fprintf(stdout, "The status is %d\n", &status);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because you do not initialize the pointer you're using, and therefore you are invoking *undefined behavior*, which means that, quite literally, *anything at all* might happen.  Try changing `status` to be an `int` (instead of an `int*`):

```
int status;
/* ... */
while (waitpid(-1, &status, 0) != pid);
fprintf(stdout, "The status is %d\n", status);
```

Your code, on the other hand:

```
int * status;
```

This creates a pointer to int and does not initialize it.

```
while (waitpid(-1, status, 0) != pid);
```

Here you pass this pointer to waitpid(), which will write at the
       pointed-to location.  Since you have not initialized
       the pointer, it's writing to an *unspecified* memory
       location!  This may crash the process or overwrite
       allocated memory elsewhere, which may lead to a
       spontaneous crash later, or data corruption!

```
fprintf(stdout, "The status is %d\n", &status);
```

This prints out the address of the pointer variable -- not
       the value it points to!  Using `*status` instead of
       `&status` may allow this part to work, but you're
       still using an uninitialized pointer.

I would strongly suggest that you turn your compiler's warning settings up to the maximum (pass `-Wall` with gcc) to make it warn on everything.  It would have caught the usage of an uninitialized pointer, and it may have also warned you about using the `%d` format specifier with a pointer-type value.

Comment: I made the changes you asked. I am however getting 256 as the value of status. I was expecting -1, as the execution of execvp failed. So I tried changing _exit to _exit(-1). But now it returns 65280 always.

Comment: You can't interpret `status` directly; only the lower 8 bits refer to the process exit code.  Use `WIFEXITED(status)` to determine if the process exited cleanly, and then use `WEXITSTATUS(status)` to get the actual exit status.  (Note that negative exit codes are not well-supported; you're only guaranteed 8 unsigned bits for exit codes.)  See the [waitpid() manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) for more details on how to interpret `status`.

Comment: i didnt get you by what you said "if the process exited cleanly". Since execvp failed, the process must exit with error or (-1). I get exit status as 255, after using WIFEXITED. I think I still dont understand this very well

Comment: Classically at least, it is bits 8-15, not 0-7, that contain the status.  Bits 0-7 contain the signal and core dump information (WIFSIGNALED, WTERMSIG, and (not in POSIX) WCOREDUMP).

Comment: @haunteddevil619 You get 255 because that is the 8-bit representation of -1.  The exit status is not signed, so the -1 is interpreted as an unsigned 8-bit number, which is 255.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see; I misread the manpage (*"This consists of the least significant 8 bits of the status argument that  the  child  specified  in  a call to exit(3) or _exit(2)..."*) -- I didn't catch that this meant that the status is truncated to 8 bits of what the child exited with.

Comment: 'Tis easily misread; the information density is very high.  Fortunately, though, once learned, it doesn't change much.  Back in the days when I first encountered exit statuses, the W* macros (and the `waitpid()` system call) were not available; POSIX has had a beneficial effect.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use large numbers or negative numbers for return values, they confuse things.
As an example, on a 32 bit system:

for int: 255 is `0x000000ff` -1 is `0xffffffff`.  So if you return any of the eight bit blocks in -1 they are are all `0xff` or 255.

If you call exit(1) or exit(2) or exit(3), or some other small positive number things will play out better for you.  In the parent be sure call `WIFEXITED(&status)` first.

Since you seem to  want to use the exit status to "tell" you something about the problem that occurred try sysexits: http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=sysexits

Or simply use `EXIT SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` ex:`return EXIT_SUCCESS;` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`  which are guaranteed to work - ie., give you a success or failure as a return.